# do I run SetSPN on SharePoint server or domain controller

Tags: setspn

I am following this article and it suggest that I set SPN for the timer job and Host controller service accounts. However, when I run setSPN on sharePoint server I get account could not be found. Do I need to have domain controller admin to run this on dc server? I also heard that SPN setup is only for kerboros and I am using SP 2013 DEV Single farm NTLM.

SetSPN domain\spSearch
SetSPN domain\spfarm

Article Link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bkr_sharepoint/2014/06/09/sharepoint-2013-search-topology-activation-error-unable-to-retrieve-topology-component-health-states-this-may-be-because-of-the-admin-component-is-not-up-and-running/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the above issue, but SPN required to configure the Kerberos authentication and if you are using ntlm then no need of it.

Setspn you need domain admin or enterprise admin or special delegate permission to modify spn.